# Passing int values from one react component to another with Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to pass latitude and longitude data from one component(file) in react to the one where the google maps component is actually being constructed and rendered. Every time I try to do a console log of the parameter being passed in, it returns an empty array.

I am passing in an float value, but have tried putting this value in an array and passing that, as well as trying to pass strings, but everything returns an empty array.

```
<GoogleMapsContainer
 lat={latVal} //latVal and longVal are float values (tested using console log)
 long={longVal}
 />

---------------------------------------------------
class GoogleMapsContainer extends React.Component {
constructor(props, lat, long) { //passing in lat and long here
 super(props);
  //using console.log statement here
 this.state = {
  showingInfoWindow: false,
  activeMarker: {},
  selectedPlace: {},
  latV: lat,
  longV: long
}

// binding this to event-handler functions
this.onMarkerClick = this.onMarkerClick.bind(this);
this.onMapClick = this.onMapClick.bind(this);
}
```

I should expect to see the proper float values when i execute the console log as indicated, but it is just printing out {}. Am I passing in the values correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need to pass in additional arguments to the constructor. Just access your values via props. See codesandbox for example: https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-ellis-76bdv

```
class GoogleMapsContainer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
       showingInfoWindow: false,
       activeMarker: {},
       selectedPlace: {},
       latV: props.lat,
       longV: props.long
    }
  }
```